# Determine the area of given conformal mapping

Tags: complex-analysis

Determine the area of given mapping
$$\{z=x+iy \in \Bbb{C} | -1\lt x \le 2 ,-1\le y \lt 3\}$$
under linear transformation $T(z)=(1+i \sqrt 3)z+2-i$

here is my attempt :
Given $$T(z)=(1+i \sqrt 3)z+2-i$$ then I'll have $$u+iv=x-y\sqrt 3+2+i(x\sqrt3+y-1)$$
Hence I obtained $u=x-y\sqrt 3+2 , and \quad v=x\sqrt 3+y-1$ 
but putting value corresponding to the set i get : 
$$u+v\sqrt 3=-2-\sqrt 3$$
$$u+v\sqrt 3=10-\sqrt 3$$
$$-u\sqrt 3+v=-2\sqrt 3 -5$$
$$-u\sqrt 3 +v=-2\sqrt 3 +5$$
At this far did i do somethings wrong ? , and to determine the area I notice the figure is gonna be something like revtangle so i have determine all the the distance of intersection line and sum it . please give me some correction and thanks for your time

Comment: The effect of adding $2-i$ is just a translation, so doesn't change the area at all. All you have to do is figure out what effect multiplying by $1 + i\sqrt{3}$ has on the area, and you can just multiply this by the area of the box, since the transformation is affine.

Comment: If you recall multivariable calculus, you can use the jacobian determinant to get the (signed) factor that the area changes by.  Here, as $T$ is of the form $T = az+b$, it'll just be $T' = a$, so you just end up multiplying by that constant.

Comment: Im still dont get it , i just tryin to follow my text book , but I end up with ugly terms and number so I think i made a mistakes , thanks for your responds I'll try to learn your suggestion

Answer (score 2):

Hint. Note that
$$T(z)=(1+i \sqrt 3)z+2-i=e^{i\pi/3}(2z)+2-i.$$
Hence $z$ is dilated by a factor $2$, $60^\circ$-clockwise rotated around the origin,  and finally translated of $2-i$.
If $R$ is the rectangle $(-1,2]\times [-1,3)$, then what is the area of $T(R)$? Recall that the area is invariant under rotations and translations.